# Eliminating duplicate rows except one column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble trying to find an appropriate query(SQL-SERVER) for selecting records with condition however, the table I will be using has more than 100,000 rows and more than 20 columns.

So I need a code that satisfies the following condition:

1.)If [policy] and [plan] column is unique between rows then I will select that record

2.)If [policy] and [plan] return 2 or more rows then I will select the record which 'code' column isn't 999

3.)In some cases the unwanted rows may not have '999' in [code] column but may be other specifics

In other words, I would like to get row number 1,2,4,5,7.

Here is an example of what the table looks like

```
row #|policy|plan|code
-----------------------
  1  |  a   | aa |111
-----------------------
  2  |  b   | bb |112
-----------------------
  3  |  b   | bb |999
-----------------------
  4  |  c   | cc |111
-----------------------
  5  |  c   | cc |112
-----------------------
  6  |  c   | cc |999
-----------------------
  7  |  d   | dd |999
-----------------------
```

I'm expecting to see something like

```
row #|policy|plan|code
-----------------------
  1  |  a   | aa |111
-----------------------
  2  |  b   | bb |112
-----------------------
  4  |  c   | cc |111
-----------------------
  5  |  c   | cc |112
-----------------------
  7  |  d   | dd |999
-----------------------
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please show expected output...............

Comment: And what is your effort? What have your tried yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want this (eliminate the last row if more than one)?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
            , row_number() over (partition by policy, plan
                          order by code desc
                         ) AS RN
            , COUNT(*) over (partition by policy, plan) AS RC
      from t
     ) t
where RN > 1 OR RN=RC;
```

Output:

```
    row policy  plan    code    RN  RC
1   1   a   aa  111 1   1
2   2   b   bb  112 2   2
3   5   c   cc  112 2   3
4   4   c   cc  111 3   3
5   7   d   dd  999 1   1
```

Comment: @winery I used `plan` as you wrote, but it is possible you should use `[plan]` in MSSQL

Comment: Thank you for your approach, this is exactly what I want. Also thanks for mentioning about [plan].

Comment: You should mark the answer that resolved your question.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a prioritization query.  You an use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by policy, plan
                                order by code
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The expected output makes this a bit clearer:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by policy, plan
                          order by (case when code = 999 then 1 else 2 end) desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The OP wants all codes that are not `999` unless the only codes are `999`.  So, another approach is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.code <> 999
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.code = 999 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.policy = t.policy and t2.plan = t.plan and
                        t2.code <> 999
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what if the unwanted row is not always 999 but depends on the condition and can not be prioritize how can I do this.

Comment: @winery . . . This question specifies that 999 is the "unwanted" row.  If you have another question, it should be asked as another question.  However, it is easy enough to put a condition in the `case` in the `order by` to implement other logic.

Comment: Okay I think I get the idea. Thanks you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([row] int, [policy] varchar(1), [plan] varchar(2), [code] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([row], [policy], [plan], [code])
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'aa', 111),
    (2, 'b', 'bb', 112),
    (3, 'b', 'bb', 999),
    (4, 'c', 'cc', 111),
    (5, 'c', 'cc', 112),
    (6, 'c', 'cc', 999),
    (7, 'd', 'dd', 999)
;
with cte 
as
(
select *,
 row_number() over (partition by policy, [plan]
                                order by code
                               ) as seqnum
      from #Table2
  )

  select [row], [policy], [plan], [code] from cte where seqnum=1
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried but it says " Vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change publicly displayed post score." I think that's because I'm just a new user.